# VS 2012 Publish Website dialog box

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, vs-web-site-project

I am attempting to publish a website using VS 2012 within the company, however, when I select "Publish Website" from the solution explorer, I get this dialog box

[image]

What I am looking for, is this dialog box:

[image]

Any ideas how to go about retrieving the desired dialog box?

Comment: Are you shure that your project is a Web Application? It seems like a Web Site

Comment: This is a website, not a web application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying VS 2012 Update 4 resolved the issue.